# Check in javascript in the select

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

How can i check the select items in javascript / jQuery.
I want check in javascript. When you clicked on value limburg and brabant. But how can i select in javascript this options?
I have this code:

```
<form action="/" method="post" class="clearfix">
    <fieldset class="clearfix">
            <div class="field">
                    <select>
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Kies een regio?</option>
                            <option value="Limburg">Limburg</option>
                            <option value="Brabant">Brabant</option>
                    </select>
            </div><!-- /field -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question. Are you asking how to use JavaScript (with jQuery) to change which item is selected? Or asking how to react when the user changes which item is selected? Or...?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to bind the change event to the select box and put your filtering in there, it would be best to assign an id or class to the select element so it can be specifically selected but the following code should alert to the screen when either of these options are selected.

```
 $(".field select").change(function() {
     if($(this).val() === "Brabant") {
         //Brabant was selected
         alert("Brabant");
     }
     if($(this).val() === "Limburg") {
         //Limburg was selected
         alert("Limburg");
     }
 });
```

If you just want to know what the current value of the selected element to you can do

```
var selecteditem = $("select").val();
if(selecteditem === "Limburg" || selecteditem === "Brabant") {
         alert("'Limburg' or 'Brabant'");
}
```

However this will not automatically trigger anything when the value is changed, to do that, this could be for validation purposes that you would do this to check that it is one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, you want to check the value of the selected option. You can do that by simply checking the value of the `select` element. With jQuery, that's as simple as:

```
$("select").val();
```

You probably want to bind an event handler to the change event so you can check the value when it changes:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    if(this.value === "Limburg") {
        //Limburg was selected
    }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2EFTZ/) of that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood your question, but to change the selected value, you can do something like

```
$('select').val('Limburg'); // to select limburg
```